# Why do we need to iterate through row length for column in 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

I was studying multidimensional array basics and the first doubt that i have come across is in the column loop for length of it why do i need to go through the row length and not only array.

Here is the loop and program i am talking about. Also what will happen if i use simple array length thing in column loop.  I have checked myself by running the program but did not get the proper answer. I understand it might sound a very basic questions, but i am beginner on this and it would be great if someone can bail me out on this.

```
public class multiarray {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a[][] = {
            {
                56, 78, 967, 7878
            }, {
                4774, 5757, 78, 98
            }
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.println(a[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly welcome to programming. Now seeing that you have the 'proper answer', why don't you include it in your question so that we can help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 2d array looks like this:

```
       col 0   col 1   col 2   col 3
row 0: 56,     78,     967,    7878
row 1: 4774,   5757,   78,     98
```

The dimension is **2x4** (2 rows, 4 columns). If you would use `a.length` (= 2) instead of `a[i].length` (= 4), to acces the *column* values, your loop would miss the last two columns, since the number of rows differ from the number of columns.

You could use `a.length` for both *row* and *column*, if you have a "quadratic" array like 2x2 or 4x4.

Comment: great..this is the explanation i was looking for..kindly confirm if i am correct: a.length gives me how many 1d arrays i am using so these are 2 and a[i].length gives me the length of each row and hence the correct columns

Comment: Yes, that is correct. And you should always use `a[i].length` instead of `a[0].length`, because each row could have a different length.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two different length measurements because there are two different lengths. You're array is effectively a 2x4 grid of numbers:

```
56   78   967 7878
4774 5757 78  98
```

If you're talking about rows, you only have two of them (indexes 0 and 1). To loop over all of them, you should use the length of your array. This is how your outer loop works. To access each inner element, you need to loop over your row lengths. To find out how big a row is, you need to take the length of an inner array. This is what you're inner loop does.